# build-essential installation failing

Tags: software-installation, eclipse, qt

I am having trouble accessing the several critical header files that show to be a part of the build process.

The Ubuntu Software Center shows that build-essential is installed:

[image: build-essential-image]

Next I did the following two commands, which did not improve the problem:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
[sudo] password for: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Dump of headers after installation attempts.

```
/usr/include/boost/interprocess/detail/atomic.hpp
/usr/include/boost/interprocess/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_atomic.hpp
/usr/include/qt4/Qt/qatomic.h /usr/include/qt4/Qt/qbasicatomic.h
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qatomic.h
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h
/usr/share/doc/git-annex/html/bugs/git_annex_unlock_is_not_atomic.html
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/arc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/avr32/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/blackfin/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/cris/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/frv/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/h8300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/hexagon/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/ia64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/m32r/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/m68k/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/metag/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/microblaze/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/mips/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/mn10300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/parisc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/powerpc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/s390/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/score/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/sh/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/sparc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/tile/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/arch/xtensa/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/include/asm-generic/bitops/ext2-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/arc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/avr32/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/blackfin/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/cris/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/frv/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/h8300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/hexagon/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/ia64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/m32r/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/m68k/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/metag/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/microblaze/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/mips/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/mn10300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/parisc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/powerpc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/s390/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/score/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/sh/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/sparc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/tile/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/arch/xtensa/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/include/asm-generic/bitops/ext2-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/arc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/avr32/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/blackfin/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/cris/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/frv/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/h8300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/hexagon/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/ia64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/m32r/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/m68k/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/metag/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/microblaze/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/mips/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/mn10300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/parisc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/powerpc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/s390/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/score/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/sh/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/sparc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/tile/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/arch/xtensa/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/include/asm-generic/bitops/ext2-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/arc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/avr32/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/blackfin/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/cris/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/frv/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/h8300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/hexagon/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/ia64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/m32r/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/m68k/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/metag/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/microblaze/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/mips/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/mn10300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/parisc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/powerpc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/s390/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/score/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/sh/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/sparc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/tile/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/arch/xtensa/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/include/asm-generic/bitops/ext2-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/arc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/avr32/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/blackfin/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/cris/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/frv/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/h8300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/hexagon/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/ia64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/m32r/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/m68k/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/metag/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/microblaze/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/mips/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/mn10300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/parisc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/powerpc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/s390/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/score/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/sh/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/sparc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/tile/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/arch/xtensa/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/include/asm-generic/bitops/ext2-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-20-generic/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/arc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/avr32/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/blackfin/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/cris/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/frv/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/h8300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/hexagon/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/ia64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/m32r/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/m68k/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/metag/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/microblaze/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/mips/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/mn10300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/parisc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/powerpc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/s390/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/score/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/sh/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/sparc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/tile/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/arch/xtensa/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/include/asm-generic/bitops/ext2-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-22-generic/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/arc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/avr32/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/blackfin/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/cris/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/frv/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/hexagon/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/ia64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/m32r/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/m68k/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/metag/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/microblaze/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/mips/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/mn10300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/parisc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/powerpc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/s390/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/score/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/sh/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/sparc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/tile/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/arch/xtensa/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/include/asm-generic/bitops/ext2-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-generic/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-lowlatency/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/arc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/arm64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/avr32/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/blackfin/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/cris/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/frv/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/h8300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/hexagon/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/ia64/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/m32r/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/m68k/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/metag/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/microblaze/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/mips/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/mn10300/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/parisc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/powerpc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/s390/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/score/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/sh/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/sparc/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/tile/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/arch/xtensa/include/asm/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/include/asm-generic/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/include/asm-generic/bitops/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/include/asm-generic/bitops/ext2-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/include/asm-generic/bitops/non-atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/include/linux/atomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/ubuntu/lttng/lib/ringbuffer/vatomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/ubuntu/lttng/wrapper/ringbuffer/vatomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/ubuntu/lttng-modules/lib/ringbuffer/vatomic.h
/usr/src/linux-lts-saucy-3.11.0/ubuntu/lttng-modules/wrapper/ringbuffer/vatomic.h
```

Yes, I know there are multiple headers of the same type here, but they are different versions.  Version "linux-headers-3.14.4-031404" shows to be the latest.

Ubuntu shows "Nothing needed to be installed."

However, the following C/C++ headers files show to be missing for Eclipse and QT4.

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/atomic.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>
```

This problem appears on my 32-bit version of Ubuntu and on both of my 64-bit versions.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: My suggestion,  clean old headers and try again

Comment: The `build-essential` package is a convenience package that only installs the basic build dependencies needed by most packages. The header files you require are part of the linux kernel, so perhaps you are trying to build a kernel driver. Maybe you can clarify your question to state why you think you need this set of header files and simply ask how to install them and how to inform Eclipse where they are?

Comment: You seem to have a lot of junk headers, try `apt-get purge linux-headers-*` then `apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: Yes, you are right I am reporting an application that will access the kernel.

I did rebuild the kernel on the 32-bit computer a few days, but no change in being able to access critically needed headers.


Also, the Purge had NO Effect! see below.
----------

    :~$ sudo apt-get purge linux-headers
    [sudo] password for ??: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Virtual packages like 'linux-headers' can't be removed
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

----------

Comment: You did `sudo apt-get purge linux-headers` but need to do `sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-.`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to compile a project that uses header files from the Linux kernel, either a kernel driver or some other project that uses Linux kernel data structures and APIs. Kernel development is a very specific use case that is not covered by the [build-essential](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) [image: Install build-essential] package, so it is no surprise that installing build-essential is not automatically making these header files available to you.

To install these header files, you will want to make sure that the [linux-headers-generic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-headers-generic) [image: Install linux-headers-generic] package is installed. This will install the header files corresponding to the current version of the kernel provided by the Ubuntu repositories.

Even after they are properly installed, these header files are not installed in the default system include path (in the `/usr/include` directory) because they are not intended to be included by host libraries and applications. Instead they are installed in a versioned directory specific to each installed copy of the kernel.

The canonical way to locate Linux kernel header files once they are installed for your kernel version is to look in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include`, where `$(uname -r)` is a shell substitution for the current kernel version:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/
```

Once you have ensured that the header files package is installed, you will have to point your build system to the Linux kernel include path. If you are working with a Makefile-based or Automake project, this could be done with a `CPPFLAGS` variable in the project's Makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/include
```

Now, if you are building a Linux kernel module there are specific ways to set up your project Makefile to integrate with the Linux kernel build system, see for example

- [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html)
- [Makefile for Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4133338/384593)